# adding more than one value in replace method or split method

Tags: java, android

I created an app that has one Text View and Edit Text. If the user writes something in, It counts the words. I defined space as split but I need more items as split, for example, every time user types comma or period it splits as well as space. Please help me.

Here's my code:

```
package com.farmani.wordcounter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
EditText et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
     et = findViewById(R.id.et);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
        {

        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)      
        {

            String text = et.getText().toString();
            text = text.replace("\n "  , " ");
            String[] textArray = text.split(" " );
            tv.setText("Number of Words: " + textArray.length);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
        {

        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: Try using regex or common lang string utils library

Comment: use a regular expression in place of \n that defines your own characters.

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: this question is about Java, not an Android Studio question. The title of the question may be changed

Comment: you are right . I just wanted to narrow it down to android usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to split with multiple delimeter then use this

```
yourString.split("[ ,]");  // this will split whenever either space or comma will be encounter
```

Comment: Thanks a million.It worked very well but now I got another problem.when I go to next line it counts it as well

Comment: Sorry buddy your answer was more technical and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change your splitting to this instead `... = text.split(" |,|\\.");`, This is because String `Split` method uses a *Regex* string value as it's parameter, so you can use which *Regex* you want, and if i describe my Regex value `|,|\\.`:-

1. First space character means space is one of the delimiters.
2. The second character which is `|` means **Or**, It means first value or the second value.
3. The Third comma means comma(`,`) is one of the delimiters.
4. The fourth character is the same as the second character.
5. The 5th and 6th characters are `\` which you should use before the period(`.`) character in Regex.
6. The final character also is one of the delimiters but this is a special character so you should use this `\` character before it in Regex.

Comment: I works like a charm. Last question: If I use ? or ! or : ; should I add \\ as well like period?

Comment: Yes you need this character before them also, You can learn or read about Regular expressions, I think it's so easy and enjoyable to learn, and this is some characters which should be escaped using this character \ which in programming languages is \\ because this character alone in strings means something else, so you should use it twice in strings, The characters are : `?`, `:`, `()`, `[]`, `+`, `*`, `{}`, ...etc.

Comment: I don't know how to thank u . I have got also 2 more problems in my app: one. After deleting text from edit text my text view shows number 1 and second problem is that double space is counted as 1 word

Comment: I don't understand the first problem well but for the second problem you can change the pattern to this instead :- `" +|,|\\."`, Just add another character which is `+` this means **one or more** *spaces* because space is before it, so you can use this pattern instead yours to split by one or more spaces or a comma or a period.

Comment: Tnx a billion.  U r a life savor